# FormData with NextJS API

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to create a simple CRUD application using NextJS along with `react-redux`, so what it does is that it saves peoples contacts.So when adding a contact i am trying to send some data along with a file to a NextJS API.

**Issue**

ContactAction.js

Make a `POST` request from redux action to add a contact

```
export const addContact = (data) => async (dispatch) => {
 try {
      var formData=new FormData();
      formData.append('name',data.Name);
      formData.append('email',data.Email);
      formData.append('phone',data.Phone);
      formData.append('image',data.Image);
      let response= await Axios.post(`http://localhost:3000/api/contact/addContact`,formData,{
         headers:{
             'x-auth-token':localStorage.getItem('token')
         }
      });
   } catch (error) {
       console.log(error);
   }
}
```

addContact.js

This is the API route in `/api/contact/`

```
  const handler = async (req, res) => {
   switch(req.method){
    case "POST":{
       await addContact(req,res)
       }
     }
   }
   const addContact = async  (req, res) => { 
     console.log(req.body);
    // do some stuff here and send response
   }
```

this is what i get in the terminal after the log,also the file is Gibberish as well when logging `req.files`

[image]

**Current effort**

I tried using third party packages such as `formidable` and `formidable-serverless` but got no luck. so after a day i made it work with a package called `multiparty`.

addContact.js

```
  const handler = async (req, res) => {
   switch(req.method){
    case "POST":{
      let form = new multiparty.Form();
      let FormResp= await new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
       form.parse(req,(err,fields,files)=>{
        if(err) reject(err)
        resolve({fields,files})
        });
      }); 
      const {fields,files} = FormResp;
      req.body=fields;
      req.files=files;
       await addContact(req,res)
       }
     }
   }
   const addContact = async  (req, res) => { 
     console.log(req.body); //Now i get an Object which i can use
    // do some stuff here and send response
   }
```

The above solution is obviously redundant and probably not the best way to go about it plus i don't want to add these 7 8 lines into each route.

what am i doing wrong? why `formData` doesn't seem to work with NextJS API (when it works with the Express server)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) uses `multipart/form-data` format. That is not a simple `POST` request with a body. It is generally used for uploading files, that's why it needs special handling. As an alternative, you could use `JSON`.

Comment: I get that much Ivan but i won't be able to access the files if i use `JSON` . the problem here is i want the file with the text fields. if it wasn't for the file a simple Object instead of `formData` would be enoughob

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but expressjs also needs a third-party module in order to handle `multipart` form. If you are sending `binary` data you have no other choice than to use `multipart` form. So your example is ok.

Comment: You are correct. I was hoping for a better approach to the problem but i guess this one will have to do.

Answer (score 15):

This works fine in next-13

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
export async function POST(request: NextRequest, response: NextResponse) {
  console.log(await request.formData())
  return new NextResponse("Thank you")
}
```

As simple as that !

Comment: @france1 that's upto your business logic, is it not :P

Comment: the thing is, I got to store some bytes with `fs`, however, the form element does not seem to contain bytes, even though it is "blob". It isn't even of type "blob", but it's called "blob".

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution, i hope this helps anybody.

First of all you need to install `next-connect` and `multer` as your dependencies.

Now you can use this API route code.

```js
import nextConnect from "next-connect";
import multer from "multer";

const apiRoute = nextConnect({
  onError(error, req, res) {
    res.status(501).json({ error: `Sorry something Happened! ${error.message}` });
  },
  onNoMatch(req, res) {
    res.status(405).json({ error: `Method "${req.method}" Not Allowed` });
  },
});

apiRoute.use(multer().any());

apiRoute.post((req, res) => {
  console.log(req.files); // Your files here
  console.log(req.body); // Your form data here
  // Any logic with your data here
  res.status(200).json({ data: "success" });
});

export default apiRoute;

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false, // Disallow body parsing, consume as stream
  },
};
```

Comment: i thought it doesnt work, but i missed the `bodyParser` config export, its necessary. please highlight those. Thanks

Comment: Is this how hard file upload on next? damn, thats alot

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example about uploading file with Next.js:

https://codesandbox.io/s/thyb0?file=/pages/api/file.js

The most important code is in pages/api/file.js

```
import formidable from "formidable";
import fs from "fs";

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false
  }
};

const post = async (req, res) => {
  const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.parse(req, async function (err, fields, files) {
    await saveFile(files.file);
    return res.status(201).send("");
  });
};

const saveFile = async (file) => {
  const data = fs.readFileSync(file.path);
  fs.writeFileSync(`./public/${file.name}`, data);
  await fs.unlinkSync(file.path);
  return;
};
```

Generally speaking,in your api file,you should disable the default bodyParser,and write your own parser

Comment: Providing link is not sufficient, Please add sample code here and explain the code a bit for everyone to understand

Comment: This method wont work on App Router

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way I did in Next.js V13 send a request from client side to next.js server.

1. Client

```
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file, file.name);
    const response = await fetch(`/api/{nextjs_server}`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `${token if needed}`,
      },
      body: formData,
      redirect: 'follow'
    });
```

2. Server (Next.js)

```
export const POST = async (req, res) => {
const formDataFlag = await req.formData() // this is the formData from the client
  if (formDataFlag) {
    const file = formDataFlag.get('file');
    
    const formDataToSend = new FormData();
    formDataToSend.append('file', file, file.name);

    const response = await fetch(`${actual api url}`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token if needed}`,
      },
      body: formDataToSend,
      redirect: 'follow'
    })
    const textResponse = await response.text();
    return new Response(textResponse, { status: 200 });
  }
}
```

The key is to redefine formData (in my case it's formDataToSend). Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

i found this code and it works to me in nextjs api route

```
import cookie from "cookie";

import formidable from "formidable";
import fs from "fs";
import { File } from "buffer";
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

const getDataFile = (files) => {
  const buffer = fs.readFileSync(files.filepath);
  const arraybuffer = Uint8Array.from(buffer).buffer;
  const file = new File([arraybuffer], files.originalFilename, {
    type: files.mimetype,
  });
  return file;
};


async function User(req, res) {
  const { token } = cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie);

  if (req.method === "POST" && req.query.action == "create_user") {
    
    const data = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const form = formidable();

      form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
        if (err) reject({ err });
        resolve({ err, fields, files });
      });
    });

    const { err, fields, files } = data;


    console.log("Value is ", err, files,  fields);


   
    const formData = new FormData();
    // formData.append('user', JSON.stringify(user));
    formData.append(
      "user",
      new Blob([fields.user[0]], {
        type: "application/json",
      })
    );
    
    formData.append("imageUser", getDataFile(files.imageUser[0]));

    const resPos = await fetch(`${API_URL}/user/create-new`, {
      




      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    },
      body: formData
    });

    const dataPos = await resPos.json();

    if (!resPos.ok) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: dataPos.message });
    } else {
      res.status(200).json({ user: dataPos });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

On NextJS 14, I have done like it:

On the front (pages/whatever/index.tsx):

```
interface UploadResponse {
  message: string;
  fileName: string;
}

const uploadFile = async (file: File | undefined): Promise<UploadResponse | undefined> => {
    if (!file) return undefined;

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);

    // I was using apisauce here:
    const response = await api.post<UploadResponse>('/upload', formData, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw response.originalError;
    }

    return response.data;
  };
```

On the backend (pages/api/upload.ts):

```
import formidable from 'formidable';
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  const form = formidable({});

  form.parse(req, async (err, _fields, files) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error parsing the form data.' });
      return;
    }

    if (!files.file) {
      res.status(400).json({ message: 'File upload error: No file was uploaded.' });
      return;
    }

    const [file] = files.file;
    const fileName = `${file.originalFilename}`;

    const destinationPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'public', 'files', fileName);

    fs.rename(file.filepath, destinationPath, (error) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error moving the file.' });
        return;
      }

      res.status(200).json({ message: 'File uploaded successfully.', fileName });
    });
  });
}
```